# What makes some SSL certificates "better" than others?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ca

I understand that browsers must trust a certificate authority (CA) to display a page using an SSL certificate without requiring the site visitors to trust the certificate. But I see certs sold by different companies at different prices ([some even free](https://www.startssl.com/?app=0)) but as I understand it they are not as "good." If an SSL certificate is supported by a browser and makes a page encrypted, what makes one CA's certificates better than another CA's certificate?

Comment: I like this question a lot, but I'm not sure it belongs on StackOverflow. Maybe it's more on topic at http://security.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: That probably would have been a better place to ask it, in hindsight, but I think it does fit in SO pretty well too because it relates to the SSL technology, not specific security questions about it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security and thus more suitable for http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13453/are-all-ssl-certificates-equal

Comment: There already is a [very similar question on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/13453/2435). Another point to look for is how many browsers, OSes and devices the CA cert is bundled with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These certificates differ on various aspects:

- life time: the cheapest certificates usually have a short life time, e.g. expire after a year or so and need to be recreated. This is not primary a nuisance to make you buy better certificates, but the cheap guys usually don't care as much about security and thus these certificates have a higher chance to be compromised (e.g. private key stolen) and there should have a short life time to limit the damage the attacker could do. And in case the owner of the certificates notices and cares about the compromise the certificate needs to be revoked and added to a CRL (certificate revocation list) which can thus get really big - just look at the huge CRLs of GoDaddy.
- wildcard and multiple names (subject alternative names): cheap certificates are restricted to a single host, wildcard or alternative names cost more. Usually companies rather by a certificate with multiple names or wildcards to avoid the hassle of maintaining multiple certificates, often it is also necessary if you offer the same site with multiple names (e.g. even example.com and www.example.com are different).
- how much verification is really done: the idea is, that some CAs do a better verification of the owner of the certificate. This makes the certificate more expensive (somebody has to pay for the verification) but it also makes it more trustworthy. Of course this make only sense if the CA really checks the owner. The best known example for this are the "extended validation certificates" which show up in the browser as more trusted.

Apart from that, your browser trusts about 100 different CAs from a variety of countries. In the current PKI (public key infrastructure) there is no way to restrict the impact of each of the CAs, e.g. a chinese CA can issue certificates for google.com or an american CA can issue certificates for google.cn. There is also no foolproof collision management, e.g. a certificate for the same domain could be issued by multiple CAs at the same time and the browsers would accept it.

Moreover, each of these trusted root-CAs can issue any number of intermediate CAs which in itself could issue other intermediate CAs etc. Each of these intermediate CAs has all the capabilities to issue any certificate they want, e.g. recently a sub-sub-sub-sub CA of the french CA FGC/A issued "accidentely" certificates for google.com and others, see http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/12/french-agency-caught-minting-ssl-certificates-impersonating-google/.
And, there is no public list of all the certificates a CA issued, so you can be sure that some of them sell intermediate CAs to law enforcement and for other purposes (see also http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2012/02/clarifying-the-trustwave-ca-policy-update.html).

And, of course,  CAs get also hacked, like DigiNotar and Comodo in 2011, where certificates for gmail, microsoft live etc where issued and actively used in attacks. And while DigiNotar got closed Comodo was probably too big to fail.

In summary: with the current PKI system the certificates you can trust the certificates like you would trust a combination of all the major goverments and companies - whatever this trust is :(

Comment: Great answer, but could you explain the danger of the CA issuing a cert to an attacker? How is this different from a less trustworthy CA issuing a cert while you use a trustworthy CA?

Comment: An attacker is no better or worse than anybody else for a CA. I've added more information about how trustworthy the CAs (and thus the certificates) are really, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for updating that with further information. Since any certificate approved by a browser will work, why would it matter if your cert is more trustworthy if an attacker can still potentially get a cert for another domain and do something evil like with DNS poisoning or another attack?

Comment: The certificate should guarantee, that the you connect to the right party by verifying the hostname(s) in the certificate against the URL.  This guarantee breaks, if the attacker gets access to the private key of the cert of if it gets a certificate with the same name from another CA (like by hacking a CA or paying for a trusted intermediate CA). DNS poisoning by itself is not a problem, because it changes the IP and not the hostname. And yes, that whole PKI is broken by design.

Comment: Okay, so while the browser may not block it, it's up to the user to notice the change in certificate?

Comment: Yes, but practically no user will notice. There are ways around the problem by using certificate pinning (e.g. warn if certificate has  changed) or compare against what certificates other user see (Perspectives project). But these are add-ons, so the average user will not notice.

Comment: Okay. So from that conclusion, it seems safe to find a cheap SSL cert as long as it provides the features I need (like subdomains, etc.)

Comment: Yes. But one of the features might also be that the clients want to see this cozy extended validation visualization inside the browser.

Comment: Yes, EV is one benefit of paying more which I'll have to consider.